# How do we declare import types from NPM library that has no declaration files?

Tags: javascript, typescript

For example, if I have the following in my app,

```
import Node from 'infamous/motor/Node'
console.log(Node)
```

that works just fine. But the moment I actually do something with it,

```
import Node from 'infamous/motor/Node'
console.log(new Node)
```

then TypeScript will complain because there's no type definition for `Node`. How do I define the type of Node?

The library has no type declarations of it's own. I tried something like

```
import MotorNode from 'infamous/motor/Node'

declare class MotorNode {}
console.log(' --- ', new MotorNode)
```

but I get the error

```
./src/app.tsx(6,8): error TS2440: Import declaration conflicts with local declaration of 'MotorNode'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I need to do what you are trying to do, I create an `externals.d.ts` file in which I put module augmentations for my project and make sure that my `tsconfig.json` includes it in the compilation.

In your case the augmentation might look something like this:

```
declare module "infamous/motor/Node" {
  class Node {
    // Whatever you need here...
  }

  export default Node;
}
```

I put it in a separate file because a module augmentation like this has to be global (must be *outside* any module), and a file that contains a a top-level `import` or `export` is a module. (See [this comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9748#issuecomment-232822688) from a TypeScript contributor.)

Comment: Thanks Louis! How do I get that file to be picked up by TypeScript? Specifically, I'm using ts-loader for Webpack.

Comment: Oh, I see, add it to `include` or `files`.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant by "make sure that my `tsconfig.json` includes it in the compilation."